# rails: User defined teaser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to allow users to define a teaser for their articles. We currently are using a separate field limited to 255 characters which has been working, but users would like to not have the redundant work.

My first thought is to use a specific string like `<more>` have an if statement to see if that string is in the article and only display the text before it while replacing the string with a link to the full article.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `<more>` idea. You could also add an `after_create` observer for the article that parses what they wrote and creates a teaser if the `<more>` keyword is in what they posted. That way you're not querying a giant article for just a snippet.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a bbcode style tag `[break]` or `[more]`, that way you could potentially define more tags later on as well.